# Convert CRON to RRULE for iCal calendar invite

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, rrule

In my application, I am creating meeting schedules based on Quartz cron format, which I am using to run some logic at meeting time by running scheduler.
Here is the npm I am using for CRON creation. https://vincentjames501.github.io/angular-cron-gen/

What i wanted to achieve is, Generate user define CRON and send an iCal calendar event invite with recurring schedule. So attendee should also get calendar invite and save it for reminder.

**Example:**  I want to schedule meeting on every Monday, Wednesday and Friday at 9 AM.
[image] 
**CRON :** 0 0 9 ? * MON,WED,FRI * 
**RRULE:** FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;WKST=MO;BYDAY=MO,WE,FR;BYHOUR=9;BYMINUTE=0;BYSECOND=0 
[image]

So My question, Is there any library or method available to generate RRULE syntax based on CRON expression?

Comment: We were having a similar problem. We 'fixed' it by writing our own RRULE to CRON expression, but this is not 100% working as it should. CRON cannot work decently with intervals nor can it take into account recurrence exceptions. So we also added custom calendars that attempt to exclude dates that cron cannot handle. I do hope however that Quartz will soon release ICAL support (but I doubt it, this has been asked [way back in 2017](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/issues/166)) without any official reply).